# Compile error with JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I try to compile a simple Java program with JOGL OpenGL, from the command line. In the Eclipse all works fine, when I compile it from the command line with `javac` I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLEventListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener
...
Could not find the main class: SimpleScene.  Program will exit.
```

I already add to `-classpath` **all** the .jar files I find in JOGL directory. The `Makefile` to build the program is the following:

```
SimpleScene:
  javac -Xlint:deprecation -classpath  \
  $(jogl)/joal.jar:\
  $(jogl)/jogl.os.x11.jar:\
  ...
  $(jogl)/nativewindow.awt.jar:\
  $(jogl)/jogl_cg-natives-linux-i586.jar:. \
  SimpleScene.java
```

Comment: Does `jar tf <jogl-jar> | grep GLEventListener` show anything?

Comment: `./jogl.all.jar` contains `javax/media/opengl/GLEventListener.class`, and a few other JARs as well

Comment: then add that jar to your classpath. `javac -cp jogl-all.jar <your filename>.java`

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I already add all JOGL jars

Comment: Then, can you post the exact arguments you're passing to `javac`? I believe you're missing the current path where jogl jars reside. If it's in the same directory as your main class, try `javac -cp jogl-all.jar:. MainClass.java`. Replace `:` with `;` if you're on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and figured out my simple mistake. GLEventListenere is an **interface**; not a class.

http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-beta5/javadoc_public/javax/media/opengl/GLEventListener.html

I fixed my problem after realizing this because my code that uses GLEventListener should use the keyword 'implements' instead of 'extends'.